# 'Inclusive Or' Inside a jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

This is obviously wrong, but it describes, in succinct terms, what it is that I would like to do:

```
$("#foo" | "#bar").hover(...
```

The Selector should trigger if:

- #foo is hovered over, or...
- #bar is hovered over, or...
- #foo and #bar are hovered over.

Comment: need more html detail if one is a parent of the other which would almost have to be the case for both to be hovered simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#foo, #bar").hover(...
```

On an unrelated note: since around jQuery 1.7 the proper way to attach events is using `on`, as follows:

```
$("#foo, #bar").on('hover', ...
```

Comment: Shorthand methods, like `hover`, `toggle`, etc. are not affected by 1.7 changes.